# Best Method for Restricting User in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a project with main window with buttons and of course a register/login, data and etc. Can you suggest the best method that would restrict a user to access all buttons and other events in my project?
 For example if staff access he/she only allows to view not to edit.

The problem is I have 8 modules in my main window. Each module has a function that is limited to every group, what could be the best approach in sql that provides user limited access base on group?
I have created a table in sql, with many columns (for every button). 
What is best approach to maximize the code and at the same time minimize the data usage for columns?

Comment: Give each user a numeric access level, or give each user a role, or both. As each form is loaded review the user's levels and enable the necessary controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Andrew's comment. You can set controls (such as buttons, panels, labels, etc.) to be visible or not visible. This is a simple way of allowing / disallowing the use of certain functions.

A very simple example:

```
    Button1.Visible = False
    Button2.Visible = False
    Button3.Visible = False

    Select Case GroupLevel
        Case 1
            Button1.Visible = True
        Case 2
            Button1.Visible = True
            Button2.Visible = True
        Case 3
            Button1.Visible = True
            Button2.Visible = True
            Button3.Visible = True
    End Select
```

Comment: Thank you, I get it now i just finished the login method and set a hardcoded permission. now i need to revise the login method then set a function thanks